# Rails exception_handler gem not updating 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exceptionhandler

I am using the exception_handler gem to make a custom 404 page. When I go to the 404 page on my site and it shows not found but how do I customize this page? I tried changing the routes, make errors_controller and not_found view.

**application.rb**

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
  get "/422", :to => "errors#unacceptable"
  get "/500", :to => "errors#internal_error"
```

**errors_controller.rb**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
    render :status => 404   end

  def unacceptable
    render :status => 422   end

  def internal_error
    render :status => 500   end

end
```

**app/views/errors/not_found.html.erb**

```
<label> TEST 404 Label </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to run `rails g exception_handler:views` this generated all the views in my project file now I can customize them to my liking.

Comment: I wrote and maintain the gem - if you need any direct support, you're welcome to email rpeck@frontlineutilities.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that you have configured those pages properly and that the code would work but just not for the environment that you're working in. In the directory `config/environments` you should have three files: `development, test, production`. When you're working in development it won't render those pages you've created as it's defaulting to Rails errors. You should check in `config/environments/development.rb` and see what you have `config.consider_all_requests_local` set to. You can change this to `false`, reset the router and be able to see the error pages, then swap it back to `true` when moving on to further development. Please note that the implementation you've used looks like an alternative to the exception_handler gem and would handle errors instead of that gem.

You can find more info here in Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration